Allocate quantities until total met
I want to write a T-SQL query that allocates ToAllocate numbers to the reference number by column ID1. Rank indicates the order of allocation and the last column shows the result I need.
Example:



ID1
ID2
Rank
ToAllocate
Reference
Result




xxx
a
1
100
350
100


xxx
b
2
200
350
200


xxx
c
3
100
350
50


yyy
a
1
40
100
40


yyy
b
2
70
100
60


yyy
c
3
10
100
0



This is a problem of running sum, for each id1 we have a reference qty to allocate, and depending on rank we know to which id2 allocate the resources, so for xxx, we have 350 -100 (to id2 a) -200 (to id2 b) -100 (to id2 c).
For the last id2, the reference qty is not enough so we have to use the available remainder.

You need to explain the logic here. Why does Rank 3 have the value 50? Why does Rank 2 have the value 40? Where do those values come from? Result initially looks like it's jsut the value of ToAllocate, but then it isn't. How do you get the values?

you should explain your result

The total result group by ID1 should represent the related reference number.

That doesn't explain anything, @FornSql . If I have the values A and B, and need to get C, what expression do I use for get C? A + B? A * B? (A + 5) / (B * 2)? Unless you explain the logic for the value of Result, we can't help you work out the T-SQL you need to use to get that result.

I think I have understood the question. I have edited it, @ThomA can you please reopen it?

@FornSql look for your answer here

Thank you very much @MtwStark! It helps me a lot!

I think, @MtwStark the example sufficiently explains the question. Voted to reopen.

Here is my solution as told before in the comments
;with
d as (
    select *
    from ( values
        ('xxx', 'a', 1, 100, 350, 100),
        ('xxx', 'b', 2, 200, 350, 200),
        ('xxx', 'c', 3, 100, 350, 50),
        ('yyy', 'a', 1, 40, 100, 40),
        ('yyy', 'b', 2, 70, 100, 60),
        ('yyy', 'c', 3, 10, 100, 0)
    ) x (ID1, ID2, Rnk, ToAllocate, Reference, DesiredResult)
),
n as (
    select *, SUM(ToAllocate) over (partition by id1 order by rnk) Need
    from d
)
select *, iif(Reference - need < 0, iif(abs(need-reference)>ToAllocate, 0, ToAllocate - (need-reference)), ToAllocate) CalculatedResult
from n


You can accomplish your desired results by carrying out a windowed sum over the amount you are allocating. This is simpler than the normal running total, because we're not bothered about summing the actual amounts allocated. Then we use a case expression to cover the 3 possibilities:

We can allocate all of ToAllocate
We can allocate part of ToAllocate
We can allocate none of ToAllocate

Note: We can only sum to the previous row when working out when we have space for the current row.
with cte as (
  select *
    , sum(ToAllocate) over (partition by ID1 order by Rank rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) Allocated
  from MyTable
)
select ID1, ID2, ToAllocate, Reference, DesiredResult
  , case when Reference - isnull(Allocated,0) >= ToAllocate then ToAllocate
  when Reference - isnull(Allocated,0) > 0 then Reference - isnull(Allocated,0)
  else 0 end Result
from cte;




ID1
ID2
ToAllocate
Reference
DesiredResult
Result




xxx
a
100
350
100
100


xxx
b
200
350
200
200


xxx
c
100
350
50
50


yyy
a
40
100
40
40


yyy
b
70
100
60
60


yyy
c
10
100
0
0



Fiddle
